# how could I prevent Mybatis from overwriting the already generated mapper files in DAO?

Tags: mybatis

Since the requirements are changing,I need to update the DAO's mapper files from time to time using Mybatis. And here is the problem that I got: we've already generated a set of mapper xml files and additionally,we defined our own specific elements in the mapper file.

```
<select id="selectTop20PlayerOfClassicCard" resultMap="CollectionRankingMap">
    SELECT playerid,count(cardid) from re_player_card where type in (0,1) GROUP
    BY playerid ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC limit 20;
</select>

<select id="selectTop20PlayerOfSpecialCard" resultMap="CollectionRankingMap">
    SELECT playerid,count(cardid) from re_player_card where type=2 GROUP BY
    playerid ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC limit 20;
</select>

<resultMap id="CollectionRankingMap" type="dymaic.RePlayerCardRanking">
    <!-- manually generated -->
    <result column="playerid" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="playerid" />
    <result column="count(cardid)" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="count" />
</resultMap>

<select id="getCardIdByPlayerId" parameterType="int" resultType="int">
    select
    re_player_card.cardid
    from re_player_card
    where playerid = #{playerid}
</select>
```

The 3 select statements and the resultmap are defined by ourselves. Now I'm going to regenerate the mapper files again.But I don't want these statement blocks to be overwriten. I need to keep them in the mapper file while changing the rest with Mybatis.

I'm using the Mybatis generator eclipse plugin. So is there any way to make it? I'd appreciate for you guys' help.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think MyBatis Generator Tool is capable of updating the partial content of the generated files.

If you are using MyBatis Generator Maven plugin you can add the following property in pom.xml to tell not to override the existing files and generate the files with another name.

```
<mybatis.generator.overwrite>false</mybatis.generator.overwrite>
```

PS: My above assumption is wrong.

**From MyBatis documentation:**

MyBatis generator is designed to run well in an iterative development environment, and can be included as an Ant task, or a Maven plugin, in a continuous build environment. Important things to note when running MBG iteratively include:

> 1. MBG will automatically merge XML files if there is an existing file
>    with the same name as the newly generated XML file. MBG will not
>    overwrite any custom changes you make to the XML files it generates.
>    You can run it over and over again without fear of losing custom
>    changes to you XML.
> 2. MBG will replace any XML elements that were
>    generated in a previous run. MBG will not merge Java files, it can
>    either overwrite existing files or save newly generated files with a
>    different unique name. If you make changes to the generated Java files
>    and run MBG iteratively you will have to merge the changes by hand.
>    When run as an Eclipse plugin, then MBG can automatically merge Java
>    files.

Answer (score 2):

**Put your changes into another mapper XML file**

1. Take the existing file copy, e.g. `MyMapperBits.xml` and I choose to change the namespace `..."http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd"> <mapper namespace="MyMapperBitsMapperNameSpace">`
2. Add the `MyMapperBits.xml` to the references in your main mybatis configuration file. In this example the `package name` items also contain various XML mappers, that I have configured mybatis generator to create.

   ```
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="com/example/extended/xmlmapper/MyMapperBits.xml" />
        <package name="com.exmaple.generated.xmlmapper.input_output"/>
        <package name="com.exmaple.generated.xmlmapper.pg_schema_1"/>
        <package name="com.exmaple.generated.xmlmapper.pg_schema_2"/>
   </mappers>
   ```
3. You then can access the "SQL" with MyMapperBits.xml by accessing it via the namespace defined in the file

   ```
   sqlSession . selectList(
   "MyMapperBitsMapperNameSpace.selectTop20PlayerOfClassicCard" ) ;
   ```

Comment: thanks! but... the question was asked 2 years ago.. I've migrated from mybatis to jpa+hibernate.